# Deterministic Finite Automata pattern

Tags: algorithm, computer-science, finite-automata, dfa

I'm trying to solve this problem using `Deterministic Finite Automata` :

```
inputs:     {a,b}
conditions: 
a. must have exactly 2 a  
b. have more than 2 b
```

so a correct input should be like this `abbba` or `bbbaa` or `babab`

now my question is, "is there a pattern to solve this things?"

Comment: Start by drawing out the states that the automata may be in. Ex: If your machine finds a single 'a', what valid transitions may it make from that state? Then from each of those, keep following transitions until you have covered all cases.

Comment: I'm having a hard time solving 2 conditions

Comment: You're really looking for more of an algorithm than a pattern.

Comment: @RBarryYoung can you suggest one?

Comment: @newbie I like Csaba Toth's answer.

Comment: @RBarryYoung its a bit blurry to me but i agree to you. I just don't quite get how did he came up with that idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is a pattern. You can take each statement and deduct pre-states from them. Then you take the cross-product of those pre-states, which will comprise the final states. In this example:

a. will yield states: 0a, 1a, 2a, 2+a (you've seen 0 a, 1 a, 2 as or more than 2 as)
b. will yield states: 0b, 1b, 2b, 2+b (you've seen 0 b, 1 b, 2 bs or more than 2 bs)

The cross product of these states result in 4x4=16 states. You'll start from {0a,0b} states. The inputs can be 3 types: a, b or something else.
From that you should be able to go. Do you need more help?

(Are we solving homework?)

Comment: sorry i don't quite get you, in the letter a. u gave 4 states which is 0a, 1a, 2a, 2+a (if i'm not mistaken) why did you give 4 states if the only need a's to be accepted is just 2? does 3 states will not do the trick? and how do i combine these two machine? (again if i'm not mistaken because it looks like 2 machine to me, machine `a` and `b`)

Comment: @newbie the 2+a state means "greater than two" which you need to know because that means that the string is not a match.

Comment: Terminology check: as I noted above, what's being discussed in this thread is really algorithms and not patterns.

Comment: @Csaba Toth how did you come up with 4 state with the first machine?

Comment: @newbie: yes, because if you get more than 2 "a"s, then you wont' meet the criteria, and you should be able to track that fact.

Comment: @Csaba Toth oh i get it you also included that trap state there. How accurate is your formula to get the number of all state? i mean the `4x4=16` ?

Comment: @newbie: it's accurate. You have to multiply them. The drawback is that as you increase the number of conditions, they yield more "pre-state" counts, and the multiplication formula result in exponential state count. It'll "explode". 16 is even a little big. I guess your task is to realize, that the generation of the automata can be automated, and this way you won't have to draw lets say 4*4*4 states (like if there was a 3rd condition for "c" letters) or more.

Comment: Is this cross multiplication also applied to `either` and `or` conditions? this seems very helpful, so i can solve this with 2 separate paths from the state 0 and with 16 states all and all?

Comment: And also another question what if the condition for the `c` doesn't end up with `4 state`? ex: `5 state`? the formula will be like this? `4x4x5`?

Comment: @newbie: you mean the either and or logical connection between the condition statements? Normally predicates connect to each other with logical and operation. This means that there are no "separate paths", the automata always has to exactly know where it is in terms of condition.

Comment: @newbie: yes, if c's predicate would yield a state count of 5, the final state count would be 4*4*5. See it is exponential, blows up easily. But that doesn't matter that much (which point can come soon btw) if you can generate the states automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Always draw such things first.

Feel free to give states any meanings. What you need here is states like: `q2: (1 b, 2 a's)`. Draw states like this, until the accept state and connect them with lines. The accept state is `qx: 2 a's 3 b's`.

After reaching the accept state, if input is "b" that line goes to itself, the accept state. If the input is "a", draw a new state, that will get into an endless loop and goes into itself no matter what the input is.

(are we helping for an exam here?)

Comment: edited, but does it matter too much? you only should add one more state. if you want i can draw and paste it, but you didn't ask for the exact solution. you asked for pattern to solve these things.

Comment: actually i make that up problem , it's just similar to what my professor gave me, and also i want to solve it my self but i'm really having a hard time when with conditions with `and` and `or` can you tell how do you solve this kind of problem?

Comment: or's generally have multiple accept states. each or'ed statement should have an accept statement of itself. and's has one accept state which conforms all of the statements.

Comment: as i advised before, feel free to sketch random things first. write down a number of accepted words to try on state diagram after drawing it. and drawing the state diagram, do draw states and links for the shortest accepted word and draw the rest after that.